# Openlayers save map as png gives SecurityError: This operation is insecure

Tags: openlayers

I need to add a command to save my map as png or jpg. I use Openlayers 6 and I added the code found on the examples as follows:

js

```
document.getElementById('export-png').addEventListener('click', function () {

  map.once('rendercomplete', function () {
    const mapCanvas = document.createElement('canvas');
    const size = map.getSize();
    mapCanvas.width = size[0];
    mapCanvas.height = size[1];
    const mapContext = mapCanvas.getContext('2d');
    Array.prototype.forEach.call(
      map.getViewport().querySelectorAll('.ol-layer canvas, canvas.ol-layer'),
      function (canvas) {
        if (canvas.width > 0) {
          const opacity =
            canvas.parentNode.style.opacity || canvas.style.opacity;
          mapContext.globalAlpha = opacity === '' ? 1 : Number(opacity);

          const backgroundColor = canvas.parentNode.style.backgroundColor;
          if (backgroundColor) {
            mapContext.fillStyle = backgroundColor;
            mapContext.fillRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
          }

          let matrix;
          const transform = canvas.style.transform;
          if (transform) {
            // Get the transform parameters from the style's transform matrix
            matrix = transform
              .match(/^matrix\(([^\(]*)\)$/)[1]
              .split(',')
              .map(Number);
          } else {
            matrix = [
              parseFloat(canvas.style.width) / canvas.width,
              0,
              0,
              parseFloat(canvas.style.height) / canvas.height,
              0,
              0,
            ];
          }
          // Apply the transform to the export map context
          CanvasRenderingContext2D.prototype.setTransform.apply(
            mapContext,
            matrix
          );
          mapContext.drawImage(canvas, 0, 0);
        }
      }
    );
    mapContext.globalAlpha = 1;

    if (navigator.msSaveBlob) {
      // link download attribute does not work on MS browsers
      navigator.msSaveBlob(mapCanvas.msToBlob(), 'map.png');
    } else {
      const link = document.getElementById('image-download');
      link.href = mapCanvas.toDataURL('image/jpeg');
      link.click();
    }
  });
  map.renderSync();

});
```

HTML

```
<button name="Screenshot" class="" data-tooltip="Click to take a screenshot" data-position="right center" > 
    <a id="export-png"><img class="icon-sidenav" src =  <?php echo get_stylesheet_directory_uri() .'/map/img/noun-screenshot-3638320.png'?> alt="Screenshot"/></a>
     <a id="image-download" download="map.png"></a>
</button>
```

I receive a message of security error on the line `mapCanvas.toDataURL('image/jpeg')`

I added the crossoOrigin='anonymous' in my layers' source.

Am I doing something wrong? I tested on Firefox, Safari and Chrome and the response was always the same

Comment: It wil be due to tainted canvas - you need specify `crossOrigin: 'anonymous',` on any tile sources, image sources and icons which do not default to that.

Comment: Thanks @Mike, it worked! I didn't know that I had to specify `crossOrigin: 'anonymous'` to the icons as well. I have other elements (like a legend) that are built outside Openlayers map. Those are not taken in the screenshot. Do you have any suggestions how to get these? Thanks

Comment: That code only works with canvas, to include other elements such as controls you need html2canvas or similar utility as in https://openlayers.org/en/latest/examples/print-to-scale.html